# Rename iptables port names

Tags: iptables

Is it possible to rename the services iptables shows behind each port? If I add a rule for port 80 for example, `iptables -L` will not show `80` but `http`. There are cases however, where the wrong service is displayed, such as `urd` for `465` where I actually use SMTP over SSL.

Edit: I know I can `iptables -L -n` to display the numbers, but I was wondering if it's possible to rename the non-nummeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names are based on `/etc/services`